# How to create co-occurrence matrix from pandas two column?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a small dataset, for example :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 'b': [11,22,11,22,33,11,22,44,11,22]})
df
```

[image]

I want to find out the co-occurrence of column b values for the column a.

What I tried :

```
df_co = pd.get_dummies(a.a).groupby(a.b).apply(max)
df_co
```

But this is not a co-occurrence matrix. So I also tried this:

```
df_co.T.dot(df_co)
```

which gives me:

[image]

Is this a correct method to calculate the co-occurrence matrix?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['a'], df['b'])`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.pivot` with a dummy column to represent count=1

```
df.assign(v=1).pivot('a','b').fillna(0)
```

```
      v               
b    11   22   33   44
a                     
1   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
3   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
5   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
6   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7   0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
8   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
9   1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
10  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
```

---

Or, as @Quang Hoang suggested, try `pd.crosstab`